# WP REST API returns combination of HTML and JSON

Tags: android, html, json, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

**i am new in wordpress. i want to get wordpress pages content into android app.
I have following url.**

https://servicetie.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/567

i attached its response. it is combination of html and json and it does not retrieve only content in android

```
  String url = "https://servicetie.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/567";

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                Log.e("con", s);
                gson = new Gson();
                mapPost = (Map<String, Object>) gson.fromJson(s, Map.class);
                mapTitle = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("title");
                mapContent = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("content");
                String render = mapContent.get("rendered").toString();
                Log.e("content", render);
         
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                // Toast.makeText(Post.this, id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }){

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                params.put("Accept", "application/json");
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Post.this);
        rQueue.add(request);
    }
```

**its response in android is**

`{"id":567,"date":"2024-01-11T10:32:01","date_gmt":"2024-01-11T10:32:01","guid":{"rendered":"https:\/\/www.servicetie.com\/?page_id=567"},"modified":"2024-01-28T14:18:00","modified_gmt":"2024-01-28T14:18:00","slug":"vision","status":"publish","type":"page","link":"https:\/\/www.servicetie.com\/vision\/","title":{"rendered":"Vision"},"content":{"rendered":"\t\t<div data-elementor-type=\"wp-page\" data-elementor-id=\"567\" class=\"elementor elementor-567\" data-elementor-post-type=\"page\">\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"elementor-element elementor-element-4233635 e-flex e-con-boxed e-con e-parent\" data-id=\"4233635\" data-element_type=\"container\" data-settings=\"{&quot;content_width&quot;:&quot;boxed&quot;}\" data-core-v316-plus=\"true\">\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"e-con-inner\">\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"elementor-element elementor-element-72d13cb elementor-widget elementor-widget-spacer\" data-id=\"72d13cb\" data-element_type=\"widget\" data-widget_type=\"spacer.default\">\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"elementor-widget-container\">\n\t\t\t<style>\/*! elementor - v3.19.0 - 07-02-2024 *\/\n.elementor-column .elementor-spacer-inner{height:var(--spacer-size)}.e-con{--container-widget-width:100%}.e-con-inner>.elementor-widget-spacer,.e-con>.elementor-widget-spacer{width:var(--container-widget-width,var(--spacer-size));--align-self:var(--container-widget-align-self,initial);--flex-shrink:0}.e-con-inner>.elementor-widget-spacer>.elementor-widget-container,.e-con>.elementor-widget-spacer>.elementor-widget-container{height:100%;width:100%}.e-con-inner>.elementor-widget-spacer>.elementor-widget-container>.elementor-spacer,.e-con>.elementor-widget-spacer>.elementor-widget-container>.elementor-spacer{height:100%}.e-con-inner>.elementor-widget-spacer>.elementor-widget-container>.elementor-spacer>.elementor-spacer-inner,.e-con>.elementor-widget-spacer>.elementor-widget-container>.elementor-spacer>.elementor-spacer-inner{height:var(--container-widget-height,var(--spacer-size))}.e-con-inner>.elementor-widget-spacer.elementor-widget-empty,.e-con>.elementor-widget-spacer.elementor-widget-empty{position:relative;min-height:22px;min-width:22px}.e-con-inner>.elementor-widget-spacer.elementor-widget-empty .elementor-widget-empty-icon,.e-con>.elementor-widget-spacer.elementor-widget-empty .elementor-widget-empty-icon{position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;margin:auto;padding:0;width:22px;height:22px}<\/style>\t\t<div class=\"elementor-spacer\">\n\t\t\t<div class=\"elementor-spacer-inner\"><\/div>\n\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t<div class=\"elementor-element elementor-element-3ee46d9 e-con-full e-flex e-con e-parent\" data-id=\"3ee46d9\" data-element_type=\"container\" data-settings=\"{&quot;content_width&quot;:&quot;full&quot;}\" data-core-v316-plus=\"true\">\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"elementor-element elementor-element-9d66bd8 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading\" data-id=\"9d66bd8\" data-element_type=\"widget\" data-widget_type=\"heading.default\">\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"elementor-widget-container\">\n\t\t\t<style>\/*! elementor - v3.19.0 - 07-02-2024 *\/\n.elementor-heading-title{padding:0;margin:0;line-height:1}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title[class*=elementor-size-]>a{color:inherit;font-size:inherit;line-height:inherit}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-small{font-size:15px}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-medium{font-size:19px}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-large{font-size:29px}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-xl{font-size:39px}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-xxl{font-size:59px}<\/style><h2 class=\"elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default\">Our Vision<\/h2>\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t<div class=\"elementor-element elementor-element-fb0488c e-con-full e-flex e-con e-parent\" data-id=\"fb0488c\" data-element_type=\"container\" data-settings=\"{&quot;co 2024-02-09 10:12:13.266  9358-9358  content                 com.alsyeddev.servicetieapp          E          <div data-elementor-type="wp-page" data-elementor-id="567" class="elementor elementor-567" data-elementor-post-type="page"> <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-4233635 e-flex e-con-boxed e-con e-parent" data-id="4233635" data-element_type="container" data-settings="{&quot;content_width&quot;:&quot;boxed&quot;}" data-core-v316-plus="true"> <div class="e-con-inner"> <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-72d13cb elementor-widget elementor-widget-spacer" data-id="72d13cb" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="spacer.default"> <div class="elementor-widget-container"> <style>/*! elementor - v3.19.0 - 07-02-2024 */ .elementor-column .elementor-spacer-inner{height:var(--spacer-size)}.e-con{--container-widget-width:100%}.e-con-inner>.elementor-widget-spacer,.e-con>.elementor-widget-spacer{width:var(--container-widget-width,var(--spacer-size));--align-self:var(--container-widget-align-self,initial);--flex-shrink:0}.e-con-inner>.elementor-widget-spacer>.elementor-widget-container,.e-con>.elementor-widget-spacer>.elementor-widget-container{height:100%;width:100%}.e-con-inner>.elementor-widget-spacer>.elementor-widget-container>.elementor-spacer,.e-con>.elementor-widget-spacer>.elementor-widget-container>.elementor-spacer{height:100%}.e-con-inner>.elementor-widget-spacer>.elementor-widget-container>.elementor-spacer>.elementor-spacer-inner,.e-con>.elementor-widget-spacer>.elementor-widget-container>.elementor-spacer>.elementor-spacer-inner{height:var(--container-widget-height,var(--spacer-size))}.e-con-inner>.elementor-widget-spacer.elementor-widget-empty,.e-con>.elementor-widget-spacer.elementor-widget-empty{position:relative;min-height:22px;min-width:22px}.e-con-inner>.elementor-widget-spacer.elementor-widget-empty .elementor-widget-empty-icon,.e-con>.elementor-widget-spacer.elementor-widget-empty .elementor-widget-empty-icon{position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;margin:auto;padding:0;width:22px;height:22px}</style>        <div class="elementor-spacer"> <div class="elementor-spacer-inner"></div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-3ee46d9 e-con-full e-flex e-con e-parent" data-id="3ee46d9" data-element_type="container" data-settings="{&quot;content_width&quot;:&quot;full&quot;}" data-core-v316-plus="true"> <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-9d66bd8 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="9d66bd8" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default"> <div class="elementor-widget-container"> <style>/*! elementor - v3.19.0 - 07-02-2024 */ .elementor-heading-title{padding:0;margin:0;line-height:1}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title[class*=elementor-size-]>a{color:inherit;font-size:inherit;line-height:inherit}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-small{font-size:15px}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-medium{font-size:19px}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-large{font-size:29px}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-xl{font-size:39px}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-xxl{font-size:59px}</style><h2 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">Our Vision</h2>        </div> </div> </div> <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-fb0488c e-con-full e-flex e-con e-parent" data-id="fb0488c" data-element_type="container" data-settings="{&quot;content_width&quot;:&quot;full&quot;}" data-core-v316-plus="true"> <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-41cd1fc elementor-widget elementor-widget-spacer" data-id="41cd1fc" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="spacer.default"> <div class="elementor-widget-container"> <div class="elementor-spacer"> <div class="elementor-spacer-inner"></div> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-b0771f0 e-con-full elementor-hidden-mobile e-flex e-con e`

Comment: Please post response in a code block to preserve the lines and make it readable.

Comment: i have edit to code block. please give me solution

Comment: Well apparently the whole text is one line only. It is unclear what the problem is. I think you posted much to much. What should we see? Which difference? Better: Post the first piece of original in a code block. And post the first piece of received in a code block. Then tell us the differences.

Comment: You get the right response. That is just what the server sends you. So unclear where you complain about. `its response in android is` No. that is not all. The server did sent more. But you grabbed that from the logcat i think and lines in logcat have limited length.

Comment: my question is that that wp-rest-api response is in html but i want extract only content from it

Comment: Which response? The response you posted is not html. I asked before to post both responses partially so we can compare.

Answer (score 0):

```
Jsoup.parse(htmlString)
```

Jsoup remove all html tags from html string. you have to add library in build.gradle

```
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
```